# Android — streaming a shoutcast metadata removed audio

Tags: android, streaming, audio-streaming

For Android ICS I have written a program that gets a Shoutcast stream, it then removes the metadata and saves it to the sdcard, works perfectly.

I would like now to send the "stream" to mediaplayer.

I have tried to use the npr streamproxy with no joy.

Is it possible to "read" my saved audio file?

Comment: What format is your saved file?